# Login middleware not working as expected Node js,, typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-session

I have the following files:

**index.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from "path";
import expressSession from 'express-session';
import { PrismaSessionStore } from '@quixo3/prisma-session-store';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

import middlewares from './middlewares/middlewares';
import userCrud from './CRUD/userCrud';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const app = express();
const port = 7000;

declare module 'express-session' {
    interface SessionData {
      isLogged:boolean;
    }
};

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${port}`);
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    let user= await userCrud.getUserByEmail(req.body.email);
    if(user){
        req.session.isLogged = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password);
        req.session.isLogged ? res.redirect('/') : res.render('login',{message:'INVALID USER OR PASSWORD'});
    }
    else{
        res.render('login',{message:'INVALID USER OR PASSWORD'});
    }    
});
app.get("/login", (req, res,) => {
    res.render('login');
});

//logout
app.get("/logout", async (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy(err=>{});
    res.render('login');
});

//login middleware
app.use(middlewares.loginMw)
//index
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
        let users = await userCrud.readUsers();
        res.render('index',{users});
});
...
```

**middlewares.ts**

```
import express from 'express';

function loginMw(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: () => any) {
    console.log(req.session.isLogged)
    req.session.isLogged ? next():res.redirect('/login');
}

export = {loginMw}
```

When I go to localhost:7000 the first time redirects to /login (which is correct), then I attempt to login with the right credentials but it redirects to /login again but you can go to any other route, as you have logged in, by writing the url like localhost:7000/route

the console.log of middleware.ts looks like this:

```
undefined (localhost:7000)
undefined (attempt with the right credentials)
true      (writing other url or a new attempt on /login route)
```

Comment: The way you've registered the `loginMw` middleware means that it will runs before every request. This includes the calls to login on the POST /login route. Probably that is the root cause of your issues.

Comment: @cdimitroulas I also tried `app.get("/",middlewares.loginMw, async (req, res) => {
        let users = await userCrud.readUsers();
        res.render('index',{users});
});` , without the `app.use` but nothing changed. thanks for your comment btw.

Comment: It seems that I solved the issue. I added the following line `req.session.isLogged==undefined?req.session.isLogged=false:req.session.isLogged;` in the `app.get('login')` Don't know if is the best but works.